# Avoid to list all records on empty search in YII Admin page

Tags: yii

In YII admin page (CRUD), by default all the records of the table will be displayed when searching with empty data in all fields.

But i need to avoid the default list. Instead, some data need to be entered in filter text box. Then only search result should shows the result based on the input. Otherwise no record should displayed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In the `search` function for your model replace the `$criteria->compare(....` with [`CDbCriteria`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria) methods that add the same condition. The [`compare`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#compare-detail) method is the only one that doesn't add a condition expression to the criteria if the attribute is empty.